# How to compute the number of steps taken by any algorithm to give the final result?

Tags: python, c, algorithm, performance, time-complexity

I want to plot a graph to compare the time complexity for a no. of algorithms doing the same thing as sorting. To do this I'm thinking to plot the **number of steps taken by an algorithm to get the final result (X-axis) versus the number of elements/ datapoints (Y-axis)**. Because I'm thinking that probably while considering the number of steps it will represent the approximate time taken by any algorithm.
For example, in case of merge sort, the time complexity is given by O(n*log2 n), where n is the height which depends upon the no. of data points/total numbers to sort, and in this way, I want to plot the time complexity for several sorting algorithms working on the same dataset in order to get a comparative graph for their best, average and worst-case scenario.

Another approach which I tried was to use time/clock function (Python3)n for the major steps for example in case of merge sort, I started the time function at the start of method doing divide, sort and merge and close it in the end but it did not work as expected. I was not able to see any deviation from the graph even for a large dataset (10000 random number) for different algorithms.

Another approach that I read about in order to plot the comparative graph for time complexity is to use the Pulse generated by CPU, but I have no idea what it is and how to compute it in the code ???

How should I go about it, what should I use in the code in order to achieve same?

Thanks

Comment: Add a counter and increment it each "step" (yes, you will have to define what you consider a "step").

Comment: For me, a step is how many times an element of my given input goes through the actual algorithm's step.

Comment: So what prevents you from counting these?

Comment: nothing but want to make sure whether that will be a correct representation of actual time complexity for a given algorithm. Also is there is any other way of doing same.

Comment: It will be an OK representation of the theoretical time complexity. Which is not always the same as the actual running time though.

Comment: The true way to do this is not a run time approach. Analyze the code and you'll know

Comment: Being able to do it automatically, and generically for any algorithm is equivalent to solving the [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), which cannot be done in turing machines

Comment: Thank you so much @EugeneSh. I'll try it

Comment: ohh.. okay thanks @amit